# json object length javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
let myObj = {
name: 'Mark',
age: 32,
working: 'yes'
}
```

How do I validate whether myObj has atleast one record? Object.keys(myObj).length gives 3 which is the length of the keys (obviously). I would like to validate if it has a value and not empty?

Comment: To clarify, you want to know if the object has at least one key with a truthy value? Eg: `{foo: "bar"}` is okay, but `{foo: undefined}` isn't?

Comment: Correct. Thats my question.

Comment: I m not sure why the question has been downvoted. The answers and response didn't sound like the question is unclear. who cares :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In es6, you can do this with a combination of `Object.values` and the array `.some` method:

```
Object.values(myObj).some(Boolean)
```

That will be true only when `myObj` contains at least one value that is not falsey. Falsey values are: `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `NaN`, `""`, and `false`.

Comment: I was looking for a one liner and this works. However I am looking at my business logic now and thinking if I have to force values on at least few fields. Thanks for your quick reply and time.

Answer (score 1):

So check properties values. You can use `some` function and check is at least one property has a value different from `null` and `undefined`.

```js
let myObj = {
   name: 'Mark',
   age: 32,
   working: 'yes'
};

const hasOne = Object.keys(myObj).some(key => myObj[key] !== null && myObj[key] !== undefined);

console.log(hasOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
let myObj1 = {
    name: 'Mark',
    age: 32,
    working: 'yes'
};

let myObj2 = {};

let myObj3 = {
    name: null,
    age: null,
    working: null
};


function validateObj(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (obj[prop]) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(validateObj(myObj1)); // true
console.log(validateObj(myObj2)); // false
console.log(validateObj(myObj3)); // false
```

Comment: All the responses are getting down voted by default. I didn't do any. Even my question is downvoted. Not sure why.

Comment: Changed the vote. Thanks for your response. I am still analyzing which one to use from all the answers I have here. Thanks for your time.